# React web authentication issue with setError and error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, frontend

I'm making a web authentication app in react based on a [YouTube video from Web Dev Simplified](https://youtu.be/PKwu15ldZ7k) (approx 20 min in)and have been running into an odd issue.

I saw someone post a similar question at the same point in development but I don't believe I have the same issue. I'm not getting any errors, the only issue I am having is on the error messages showing. When I submit an email and pair of mismatched passwords it should give me an error message, but I cannot get it to display any errors. This is the code:

**./index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './components/App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**./components/App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Signup from './Signup'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { AuthProvider } from '../contexts/AuthContext'

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Container className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
        <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "400px" }}>
          <Signup />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

**./contexts/AuthContext.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()

    function signup(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => { 
            setCurrentUser(user)
        })
        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const value = { currentUser, signup }
    
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    
}
```

**./components/Signup.js**

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';

export default function Signup() {
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
    const { signup } = useAuth();
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
            return setError("Passwords do not match");
        }

        try {
            setError("");
            setLoading(true);
            await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value);
        } catch {
            setError("Failed to create an account");
        }
        setLoading(false);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
                    {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group id="email">
                            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group id="password">
                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
                            <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
                        </Form.Group>
                    </Form>
                    <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
                        Sign Up
                    </Button>
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
                Already have an account? Log In
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

I've tried changing the [error, setError] assignment to `const [error, setError] = useState("");` and it displayed the initially assigned error properly, but it still refuses to assign any subsequent messages. I've also tried to make sure all the names are correct, and uniform. I have been troubleshooting this for a couple days now to little success. JavaScript is not my main language, and I'm still learning it so I'm sure I'm just missing something simple. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does `useAuth` look like?

Comment: I added it to the question. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I had placed the button outside of the card which caused it to not activate what it was supposed to. Moving the Button tag inside the Card tag fixed everything.